# ValueError:use a.any() or a.all() and AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'all' python

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to run this code:

```
if (numObj<Max_DetObj):
    i=0
    while (i >= 0).all():
        Moment = cv2.moments(contours[i])
        area = Moment['m00']
        if (area >Min_ObjArea):
            x=Moment['m10']/area
            y=Moment['m01']/area
            found_Obj=True
        else:
            found_Obj=False
        i=hierarchy[i][0]
```

but i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\opencv2.4.8\sources\samples\python2\Work.py", line 120, in <module>
trackObj(threshold,hsv,frame)
File "C:\opencv2.4.8\sources\samples\python2\Work.py", line 84, in trackObj
while i >= 0:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use       a.any() or a.all()
```

and when I add all() or any() in the specific line I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'all'
```

can anyone explain ?!!

Comment: What are you trying to do?  `i` is just a single number, so it has no `all`.  Why don't you just do `while i >= 0`?

Comment: When you get an error, show us the *full* stack trace, not just the exception

Comment: @BrenBarn I did but i get the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i` is a `list`. We don't have the information on what it contains, but the error and solution is clear nonetheless.

For argument, let's say `i` is:

```
i = [1, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

You cannot compare a list with `>=`. What you want to do instead is compare each element of the list. Because you're comparing to `>= 0`, it's easy enough to just check its truthiness with `any()` and `all()`:

```
>>> any(i)    # Are any of the elements of i true?
True
>>> all(i)    # Are all of the elements of i true?
False
```

So in your code, it would be:

```
while any(i):
```

or

```
while all(i):
```

Where only you know which one it should be, depending on whether you want to check if they're all >= 0, or just one would suffice.

#### [`Any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

> Return True if any element of the iterable is true. If the iterable is empty, return False. Equivalent to:

```
def any(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if element:
            return True
    return False
```

#### [`All`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

> Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the iterable is empty). Equivalent to:

```
def all(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if not element:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: I didn't really get your explanation cause 'i here is not a list it is just a variable that has 0 as 1st value and in each iteration it become i=hierarchy[i][0]
(the real loop is written in c++ and i'm trying to convert it to python https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28096936/tuts/tut2/multipleObjectTracking.cpp)

Comment: Clearly it's not. Print out `i` after each loop to verify that

Comment: I did print out i and i found that at the end of each loop it becomes list (example i=[1,-1,1,1]) and when i change it to any(i) or all(i) it says that 'int' object is not iterable !!!!

Comment: Because in the first loop you created `i = 0`. Change that to a list, such as `[1]`

Comment: thank you so much now it works (if there is any other notices about the code i'll be thankful)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you are using numpy arrays undercover so you should use numpy functions.

See this code that reproduces your stacktrace:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 15:40:47) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np 
>>> i = np.zeros(2)
>>> if i: 
...  pass
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
>>> if not i.any(): 
...   print "OK"
... 
OK
```